# Create new listadapter from a fragment. Know how to do it from an activity but not from a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have an ArrayAdapter that I would like to call (create) from a Fragment, I know how to do it from an activity but not from a fragment, perhaps one of you guys could give me the right syntax?

Anyway I try to do the following from a fragment

```
ShareHoldingAdapter adapter = new ShareHoldingAdapter(this, R.layout.listview_item_row, allShareHoldings);
```

But my Adapter has the constructor `ShareHoldingAdapter(Context portfolioFragMent, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<ShareHolding> data)` I.E its a "context" and not a "PortolioFragment" or simply a fragment

How would you change my Adapter so that it would work to call it from a fragment instead of now (from an activity?)

Here is my adapter code

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ShareHoldingAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ShareHolding>{

    Context context; 
    int layoutResourceId;    
    ArrayList<ShareHolding> data = null;
    private ShareHolder holder;
    private ShareHolding shareHold;


    private int buttonPressed = 0;
    public void setButtonPressed(int buttonPressed) {
        this.buttonPressed = buttonPressed;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    public ShareHoldingAdapter(Context portfolioFragMent, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<ShareHolding> data) {//Need to change this constructor to accept a fragment instead of an activiy (context)
        super(portfolioFragMent, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = portfolioFragMent;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        holder = null;

        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new ShareHolder();
            holder.imgIcon = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgen);
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);

            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ShareHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        shareHold = data.get(position);
        holder.txtTitle.setText(shareHold.getName());

        //buttonPressed

        switch (buttonPressed) {
        case 0: 
            holder.imgIcon.setText(Double.toString(shareHold.getSharesChangeTodayPercent()));
          break;
        case 1: 
            holder.imgIcon.setText(Double.toString(shareHold.getCurrentRate()));
          break;
        case 2: 
            holder.imgIcon.setText(Double.toString(shareHold.getNrOfSharesInPortfolio()));
          break;
        case 3: 
            holder.imgIcon.setText(Double.toString(shareHold.getTotalPercentDifference()));
          break;
        case 4: 
            holder.imgIcon.setText(Double.toString(shareHold.getTotalDiffrenceKr()));
          break;
        case 5: 
            holder.imgIcon.setText(Double.toString(shareHold.getTotalKr()));
          break;
        default: 
            holder.imgIcon.setText(Double.toString(shareHold.getBuyingRate()));
      }

        //holder.imgIcon.setText(Double.toString(weather.getBuyingRate()));
        return row;
    }

    static class ShareHolder
    {
        TextView imgIcon;
        TextView txtTitle;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to create your adapter from fragment you should call:

```
ShareHoldingAdapter adapter = new ShareHoldingAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.listview_item_row, allShareHoldings);
```

since `Fragment.getActivity()` return `Activity` which is subclass of `Context`